# Change every nth letter in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

How do I change/edit the nth letter in an array, specifically every fifth letter? I am trying to change every fifth letter's ASCII value. I'm struggling to figure out how to pick up every fifth letter from an array that I converted from a string by `my_string.split("")`. I want to use the index, but if that's not possible, other ways would be appreciated.

My code:

```
puts "Please enter your name."
user_name = gets.chomp
puts "Please enter message you would like to encrypt"
user_input = gets.chomp
fname = "#{user_name}'s Encrypted File.txt"
file = File.open(fname, "w+")
file.puts "#{user_input}"
file.close
words = user_input.split("")
words = |w|
  new = w.ord + 10
  new.chr!
  puts new
  fname = "#{user_name}'s Encrypted File.txt"
file = File.open(fname, "w+")
file.puts "#{new}"
file.close
puts "This is the text after encryption:"
file = file.open ("#{user_name}'s Encrypted File".txt)
puts "Do you want to see your original message?"
puts "Press 'Y' for Yes, press 'N' for No"
if gets.chomp == "Y"
  original = file.open ("#{user_name}'s Encrypted File".txt)
  green = original.split("")
  green.step(5).each {|five|
  five = five.chr - 10
  five.ord!
  puts original}
end
```

Comment: use a loop? provide code please

Comment: Note: if you started with a string, you don't need to convert it to an array because Ruby, like many languages, provides `[]` index access to strings.  So for example `"abcdefg"[2]` is `"c"`.  You can operate directly on the string.

Comment: Post the minimal code that is relevant to your question. Don't post the entire program.

Comment: Your code is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Given a string:

```
str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

You could use a `Range` for the string's indices:

```
(0..str.size) #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
```

[`Range#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Range.html#method-i-step) enumerates every `n`th element within the range:

```
(0..str.size).step(5).to_a #=> [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

You can pass a block to change every `n`th character:

```
(0..str.size).step(5) { |n| str[n] = str[n].upcase }

str #=> "AbcdeFghijKlmnoPqrstUvwxyZ"
```

Comment: A nice one, I did not notice yet that ranges support steppings. If str.size is evaluated only once, it should be the same speed.

Answer (score 3):

By '*change/edit the nth letter in an array*' I am assuming you want to change the array in place. We will define change as upcase the letter. Therefore:

```
arr.map!.with_index { |letter, index| index % 5 == 0 ? letter.upcase : letter }
```

Comment: This is nice for the usage of map(), but lets the whole data stream through, while only a fifth needs to be accessed.

Comment: @mvw, true, but this would rarely matter. If OP insists on a solution which doesn't iterate all items I would still prefer Stefan's solution over yours.

Comment: @mvw, lol, calm down dude. I never said I hate it, neither would I downvote it. I was just pointing out that you seem to worry too much about non-asymptotic optimizations when you should focus a little more on your style instead.

Comment: You got me, I still bow to [Real Programmers Don't Use PASCAL](http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/realmen.html).

Answer (score 1):

Or just touch every 5-th character:

```
s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
n = s.length
i = 0
while i < n
  s[i] = s[i].upcase
  i += 5
end
```

This gives

```
> s
 => "AbcdeFghijKlmnoPqrstUvwxyZ"
>
```

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully that should work for my task - much appreciated!